# error: narrowing conversion of ‘18446744069414584320ull’ from ‘long long unsigned int’ to ‘int’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]

Tags: c++

What is wrong with this piece of code? I'm using GCC 6.3.

https://ideone.com/ektGEp

> a.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:`a.cpp:26:24: error: narrowing conversion of ‘18446744069414584320ull’ from ‘long long unsigned int’ to ‘int’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <smmintrin.h>
#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <tmmintrin.h>

typedef union {
        __m64  mm64[2];
        __m128 mm128i;
} sse2_t;

#define const_epi32( i3,i2,i1,i0 )      \
            { static_cast<unsigned long long> (static_cast<unsigned long long>(i1) << 32), \
              static_cast<unsigned long long> (static_cast<unsigned long long>(i3) << 32) }

int main() {

        sse2_t arr_val[3] = { const_epi32(0,-1,0,-1),
                          const_epi32(0, 0,-1, -1),
                          const_epi32(0, 0,0, 1024) 
                        }; //error!

        sse2_t val = const_epi32(0,-1,0,-1); // ok!
        // your code goes here
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: According to the error message it’s trying to initialize an object of type `int` with a value of type `unsigned long long`, and an `int` Is too small.

Comment: @PeteBecker - Not your fault, but then the error message should say that, and not some esoteric "narrowing conversion" ISO-like speak.

Comment: @SO_fix_the_vote_sorting_bug -- part of learning a programming language is learning its terminology. Once you've grasped what a "narrowing conversion" is you're in a much better position to see when they happen and to decide whether a particular conversion is appropriate or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The types `__m64` and `__m128` are very special, representing vector registers, which means that you cannot assign values to them in the usual way (like you seem to be trying to do in your code). You need to use special load functions to put data into registers, and special store functions to get data back from there.

Here is an example of how you could load data (four floats) into a `__m128` variable:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <smmintrin.h>
int main() {
  float f[4];
  memset(f, 0, 16);
  __m128 a = _mm_load_ps(f);
  return 0;
}
```

This page has lots of info about all the different types and intrinsic functions available: https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/

Comment: yep, you are absolutely right. Your suggestion bring back to my mind that we have special load intrinsics. I rewrite const_epi32 macro as in my post below.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define const_epi32( i3,i2,i1,i0 )      \
        { _m_from_int64( (static_cast<unsigned long long>(i1) << 32), \
          _m_from_int64( (static_cast<unsigned long long>(i3) << 32) }
```

Comment: It looks strange that your macro has four input arguments i3 i2 i1 i0 but it only uses two of them; i2 and i0 are unused?

Comment: Oh. it's just snippet from real code, just to localize root cause of problem:)

Answer (score 0):

The part `const_epi32(0, 0,-1, -1)` is causing the warning since you are assigning '0xffffFFFFffffFFFF' to a 32 bit 'int' which is narrowing.

I assume the other cases do not cause a warning since the assigned value is a constant 0 which does not suffer from narrowing.

The other question is, why is `__m64` an `int`. I assume that `__m64` cannot be directly assigned to (being an MM register) and that the narrowing check (at least for constant assignment) is bogus in the compiler.

Comment: Where is this `int` it's being assigned to?

Comment: @chris: Yes! This is the actual question! :-) I assume that __m64 is not a real type to the compiler. It stands for a MM register.

Comment: @chris: it's the __m64. GCC uses the semantic of `int[2]` for __m64. But this is not necessarily a portable thing. For example, clang uses `long long[1]` instead.